# MailItem.Move method for mail that is read

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to first check if mails in a specific folder ("pending") are read. If the mail is read, move it to another specific folder ("done").

For the remaining mails in "pending", save the attachments and mark them as "read".

When I try to move each read mail from the "pending" folder to "done" with ".Move", drops

> "error 424. An object is required".

The problem is `OItem.Move OFolderDst`.

```vb
Sub MoveInbox2Reviewed()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim ONameSpace As Object
Dim OItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim OFolderSrc As Object
Dim OFolderDst As Object
Dim Path As String

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set ONameSpace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set OFolderSrc = ONameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("pending")
Set OFolderDst = ONameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("done")

Path = "C:\Users\..."

For Each OItem In OFolderSrc.Items.Restrict("[Unread] = False")
    OItem.Move OFolderDst 'The problem is here
Next

For Each OItem In OFolderSrc.Items
    OItem.Attachments.SaveAsFile Path & Attachment.DisplayName
    OItem.UnRead = False
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you show us your real code? If so, I am afraid that you have problems with the way VBA raises errors. For instance `Attachment.DisplayName` should raise an error. Please, place `Option Explict` on top of the module where this code exists. Than, as stated in the received answer, when you take elements from the iterated collection you should iterate it backwards. I would suggest to create a new variable, let us say `oItems`, previously set as `Set oItems = OFolderSrc.items.Restrict("[Unread] = False")`. Then iterate as suggested: `For i = oItems.count To 1 Step -1` and then, as suggested.

Comment: But your code should work as it is, but missing some cases of unread messages. Are you sure that a folder (child of Inbox) named "done" does exist?

Comment: Still alive? It is at least polite to check from time to time your question and answer the clarification questions...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You are right, the code is now working. I missed a dot when changing a line. Thank you so much for your time and your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time the `Move` call is made the collection is decreased by one item. So, I'd recommend using the reverse `for` loop instead for moving items from a folder. For example:

```
for i = Items.Count to 1 step -1
  Items(i).Move folder
next
```

So, in the code you may get all unread items (represented by the `Items` collection) and then call a reverse loop to move items.

Comment: I tried this, but it still drops the same error in the same line. Don't know why.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which line?

Comment: Line 19 `OItem.Move OFolderDst`

Comment: @PADARO_150 `OItem.Move OFolderDst` should not exist, anymore. It should be `Items(i).Move OFolderDst`...

Comment: It is now working. I missed a dot when changing the code. Thank u all.